# Can cpanel be setup so that every account pulls randomly from the IP pool, ensuring the IPs are being used equally in a round robin way

Tags: cpanel, whm

Can cpanel be setup so that every account pulls randomly from the IP pool, ensuring the IPs are being used equally in a round robin way.

I dont know cpanel very well, but in Directadmin and Hestia, you can have the user select the IP address from a pool. Even this would work